# There is no sound for Lenovo 3000 N100 after installing any driver on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, audio

Is there a way to fix that problem? Through the network there is a lot of forums with this question, but any answer was not satisfied. It still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try in Device Manager. Look for **Microsoft UAA Bus Driver** **for High Definition Audio**. Try to restore it in case it is broken. Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

1. right click on computer /select manage/open device manager/uninstall audio device
2. download driver from [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vpqi_9lFVXljwW5hMgXj1ZyVXx7QxC5c/view?usp=sharing) or in download attachment link
3. extract and paste it in `c` drive
4. again go to device manager and right click to scan for hardware change
5. double click on `audio device` and select generated audio device/right click for properties and select it
6. select driver tab and click update driver
7. select second option / browse my computer for driver
8. select let me pick from a list option
9. select have a disk tab
10. browse and select `c:\driver\win\audio\i386\vista\ADIHdaud`
11. then click OK to install, ignore warning messages